# Is it possible to load local data to kendo grid part by part?

Tags: c#, kendo-ui

I have huge amount of data locally, but don't want to load all to grid at a time. Is it possible to load some content to a page, then after scrolling to another, another part of local data loads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to enable [`serverPaging`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#serverpaging%20booleandefault) in the DataSource definition. You might be interested also on KendoUI Grid [`scrollable.virtual`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#scrollablevirtual%20boolean%20default).

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you are using an ORM here:

Sure just have the data access code return `IQueryable<T>`

For more info read this:

http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/ajax-binding

It explains how Kendo does the Paging and Sorting for you. So the SQL genereated will only return what is displayed on the grid and not all of your data.

From the Kendo Site:

**How do I implement paging, sorting, filtering and grouping?**

If your model supports the IQueryable interface or is DataTable the grid will do paging, sorting, filtering, grouping and aggregates automatically. For server binding scenarios no additional steps are required - just pass the IQueryable to the Grid constructor. Check the server binding help topic for additional info.

For ajax binding scenarios the ToDataSourceResult extension method must be used to perform the data processing. Check the ajax binding help topic for additional information.
If your model does not implement IQueryable custom binding should be implemented. This means that the developer is responsible for paging, sorting, filtering and grouping the data. More info can be found in the custom binding help topic.

**Important:**

All data operations will be performed at database server level if the underlying
 IQueryable provider supports translation of expression trees to SQL. Kendo Grid for ASP.NET MVC has been tested with the following frameworks:

Entity Framework

Linq to SQL

Telerik OpenAccess

NHibernate

Comment: I'm trying to use a grid with a huge amount of rows. Fetching all of the rows is very expensive process. How can i configure the grid such that every callback will return the next page, but the initial call will not need to fetch all of them at once? (from the examples it looks like the initial call is returning the complete model - and subsequent calls to the Products_Read are on the filter object. How can the initial call be filtered as well but allow for future paging - in my case I have 100k+ rows and it is impossible to do "return View(model") )
Thanks!

Comment: post a new question with some code examples, and post a link here i will try help